# Jasper Report is not showing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, ireport

I've been developing an accounting software by JAVA on NetBeans 7.3 IDE.

I used Jasper Report (iReport) to produce reports in my application. I needed to get specific data which I populate to `JTable` and get only those data to Jasper Report. So, I used `JRTableModelDataSource` to generate data on Jasper report.

Nevertheless, I failed, that means, when I click on 'show Report' button tt doesn't show anything and it shows an error on NetBeans IDE Log window as,

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:151)
    at accdat.frmJournalBatchList.btnNewActionPerformed(frmJournalBatchList.java:395)
    at accdat.frmJournalBatchList.access$400(frmJournalBatchList.java:38)
    at accdat.frmJournalBatchList$5.actionPerformed(frmJournalBatchList.java:117)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at org.jvnet.substance.utils.RolloverButtonListener.mouseReleased(RolloverButtonListener.java:109)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.digester.Digester
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 41 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 29 seconds)
```

I used following codes to populate jTable.

```
private void GetGLData(){
    try
    {            
    con = ConnectionManagerACCDAT.getConnection();
    stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM gl_bt_lst ORDER BY BT_NO ASC" );


    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) tblJournalBatchList.getModel();
    Object[] values = new Object[5];
    while (rs.next()) {
        values = new Object[5];
        values[0] = rs.getString("BT_NO");
        values[1] = rs.getString("DT");
        values[2] = rs.getString("DSCRP");
        values[3] = rs.getString("RD_2_PST");
        values[4] = rs.getString("PSTTD");


        dtm.addRow(values);
        }       
    // Close the connection after use
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    con.close(); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "Journal Batch List.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }      
}
```

and I used following codes to generate report.

```
private void btnNewActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    try
    {            
            String ReportSource = "D:/Reports/Test.jrxml";
            if (new File(ReportSource).exists() == false)
            {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please go to setting and Choose report Source");
                    return;
            }                
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(ReportSource);
            Map params = new HashMap();
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, 
                    params, new JRTableModelDataSource(tblJournalBatchList.getModel()));
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {                
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e,"reports Error  ",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Guys, where's the wrong thing that i have done. BTW, I have imported relevant Libraries to NetBeans and Used Fields Name as COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2... ect... to link report to jTable Columns.

Comment: Jasper Reports has a number of 3rd party dependencies which you need to include, in this case, it would appear you need to include the [Apache Commons Digester](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-digester/) library, but there may be more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Plese include follwing common jar files in the classpth for general web application
>   with jasper reports
>
> 1. commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
> 2. commons-digester-1.7.jar
> 3. commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
> 4. iText-2.1.7.jar
> 5. poi-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar
> 6. jasperreports-3.7.3.jar